# instanceof is accepting a string as an instance of my Type class Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, instanceof

The if statement below evaluates to true when type is a string and I can't seem to figure out why. This is my code:

```
const validateType = (instanceDescription, type) => {
    if (!type instanceof Type) {
        throw new Error(`type property of ${instanceDescription} is not 
                         a (child) instance of class Type`);
    }
}
```

I can't see the problem being in my class because it's really simple. It looks like this.

```
class Type {
    constructor(key, multipliers) {
        this.multipliers = multipliers;
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

Is there something going on with the instanceof comparison that I'm not aware of or am I just going mad. I got around it by checking if a certain property is undefined which it will be for a string but I would rather go for the more clear instanceof option

Comment: and more precisely in which language? there is not tag to mark the language.

Comment: Could you add how you are calling the `validateType` function, and with what parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parenthesis make a difference here because of [operator precendence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). `!` has a higher precedence than `instanceof` so with out the parenthesis your test is asking if `false` is an instance of `Type`:

```js
class Type {
  constructor(key, multipliers) {
      this.multipliers = multipliers;
      this.key = key;
  }
}

let t = "somestring"

if (!(t instanceof Type)) { // << note the parenthesis
  console.log("error")
}
if (!t instanceof Type) {  // << never fires
  console.log("no error")
}
```